# Adding random class on hover using setInterval, but unable to stop the loop?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, intervals

I am trying to simply loop through an array of class names when `el` is hovered using jQuery. To do so, I am using `setInterval()` which works fine, but I'm having to set this within an `.on('mouseenter')` function, so I'm therefore unable to access this to `clearInterval()` when the mouse leaves. I'm sure there is a simple solution here but unable to identify it. I've tried setting `randomClassTimer` as a global variable but in doing this I'm unable to start it when desired.

Many thanks

```
function myFunction() {
  // Vars
  var classes = [
    "class-1",
    "class-2",
    "class-3",
  ];

  // On mouseenter
  el.on("mouseenter touchstart", function () {
    // Start interval loop
    var randomClassTimer = setInterval(function () {
      // Remove all previous classes
      el.removeClass(classes.join(" "));

      // Add new random class
      el.addClass(
        classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)]
      );
    }, 300);
  });
  // On mouse leave
  el.on("mouseleave touchend", function () {
    // Stop interval loop (doesn't work!!!)
    clearInterval(randomClassTimer);
  });
}
```

Comment: because the scope of `randomClassTimer` is in the event listener so you can not access it. You should have a nice error message in your developer tools.

Comment: `var randomClassTimer; el.on("mouseenter touchstart", function () { randomClassTimer = setInterval.....`

Comment: Due to scope (as above) `clearInterval(randomClassTimer)` will be the same as `clearInterval(window.randomClassTimer)` ie an implied global variable, which will be null

Comment: Thanks for comments all, is there a better way to restructure this to make the var available?

Comment: @epascarello - this works great,t thank you! If you want to add it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted. Cheers!